# Происходит ли запрос IP-адреса от DNS сервера при использовании укороченных абсолютных путей?

Tags: html, dns, ip-address

> Вы можете встроить изображение используя абсолютный URL, например:
>
> `html <img src="https://www.example.com/images/dinosaur.jpg">`
>
> Но это бессмысленно, так как он просто заставляет браузер делать
> больше работы, запрашивая каждый раз IP-адрес от DNS-сервера. Вы почти
> всегда будете держать свои изображения для сайта на том же сервере,
> что и ваш HTML.
>
> [mdn web
> docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML)

Распространяется ли это на укороченные абсолютные пути типа `/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML`? Если нет, то получается, что предпочтение следует отдавать относительным путям...

Comment: Здесь упущен крайне важный нюанс — URL на сторонний сайт или на текущий? Если на сторонний, то, очевидно, браузеру придётся сделать DNS-запрос, чтобы узнать IP-адрес этого самого стороннего сайта. Если на текущий — разумеется, делать DNS-запрос нет никакого смысла, потому что IP-адрес текущего сайта браузер и так прекрасно помнит из предыдущих запросов. Более того, он даже переиспользует существующее HTTP-соединение с текущим сайтом

Comment: Кроме того, обратите внимание, что этот перевод устарел — в [оригинальной английской статье](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML) это утверждение [было удалено](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/22137/files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, при использовании укороченных абсолютных путей запрос IP-адреса от DNS сервера не происходит. Укороченные абсолютные пути используются для указания ресурсов на том же хосте или в той же доменной зоне, что и текущий ресурс. При обработке таких путей браузер или другое программное обеспечение сразу выполняют запрос к нужному ресурсу, не обращаясь к DNS серверу для получения IP-адреса.